# Inputs with form attribute outside the form tag are not submitting

Tags: html

I have a couple of inputs outside of a form that won't submit when submitting the form for some reason.

```
<td>
    <input type='text' form='editform' name='id' value='LIT'>
</td>
<td>
    <input type='text' form='editform' name='name' value='Lituanie'>
</td>

<td>
    <form action="datamanager" method="POST" id="editform" class="editform">
        <input required readonly type="hidden" name="target" value="Country"/>
        <input required readonly type="hidden" name="idEdit" value="LIT"/>
        <input required readonly type="hidden" id="status" name="status" value="validate"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submitEdit" class="validate-submit" value="" title="Validate"/>
</form>
```

The 3 inputs that are in the form submit properly (target, idEdit and status) but the id and name inputs just won't submit.
The weirdest part is that if I change the form attributes of the inputs and the id of the form from chrome's developer tools it then works. It's as if the browser doesn't recognize that they're linked to the form unless I change it in the developer tools...

Any ideas of what might cause that ? I've been stuck with this all afternoon when it should have been a 2 minutes thing...

Comment: You can also use an iframe or Ajax to add that functionality.

Comment: Yeah but why would I since html5 is supposed to make this possible in the simplest of way ...

Comment: @Spare - I modified your tags and clarified your title for you so someone may be able to help you better since this question is very specific to HTML5.

Comment: Because it is far more responsive and gives the developer more programming options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `input` elements within the form will submit, unless you have specified a `form` attribute.

**Option 1** - Put everything in the `<form>`

```
<form action="datamanager" method="POST" id="editform" class="editform">
<td>
    <input type='text' form='editform' name='id' value='LIT'>
</td>
<td>
    <input type='text' form='editform' name='name' value='Lituanie'>
</td>
<td>
    <input required readonly type="hidden" name="target" value="Country"/>
    <input required readonly type="hidden" name="idEdit" value="LIT"/>
    <input required readonly type="hidden" id="status" name="status" value="validate"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submitEdit" class="validate-submit" value="" title="Validate"/>
</td>
</form>
```

**Option 2** - Add the `form` attribute

If you wanted to keep your original code, add the `form` attribute to the `input`s outside of the `<form>` tag.

`<input type="text" name="lname" form="form1">`

**Important note:** Option 2 will not work in IE. Be sure to read http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_form.asp for more info on the `form` attribute.

Comment: "Only input elements within the form will submit."
that's not true since html5 implemented the "form" attribute for the input tag : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_form.asp

Comment: @Spare - that attribute isn't supported in IE, so it's probably not good practice to use it in a production environment until it's supported in all major browsers.  Also - w3schools.com is not a viable resource.  It would be better to cite MDN or W3C.

Comment: I understand the fact is that I don't wanna work around that with some JS and that your option 1 doesn't work for some reason. Can't test it further right now but I'll re-try tomorrow...
and @pattyd I did use the form attribute in my code and it doesn't work. That's the whole point of my question.

Comment: @Spare see my edit. There was a missing `</td>` tag from your original code.

Answer (score 2):

Only inputs that are inside at form can be submited.so you must surround with form tag or you should put theme into existing form.

Comment: @Spare - that attribute isn't supported in IE, so it's probably not good practice to use it in a production environment until it's supported in all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In Html only those inputs which are in form tag are submitted.

If you have multiple form tags in an HTML only those which are in "submitted" form are submitted